# Angular JS how to read the css file names which are loaded in the html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We are creating a new widget in that we are implementing a feature which tells how many css files which are included in a html page.

We need the count of css files used in the page and also the names of the css files.

I am bit new to angular and I have heard this can be done using directives but have no idea how to achieve it.

Need your help guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Is your application already in Angular? This jQuery code would do this task easily:

```
var cssList = []
$('head link[type="text/css"]').each(function(){
    cssList.push($(this).attr("href"));
});
console.log("List of files:" + cssList.join());
console.log("Number of files:" + cssList.length);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but as I mentioned in my question we want this to be implemented in angular rather than in jQuery. Can we have this code in directive way?

Comment: A directive is usually a UI component... you should use a service instead. Angular has jqLite, so you can use the same code without needing to have jQuery imported
see: [angular element documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: Hello Lucas Rodrigues! I just got [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10385700) in review. Unfortunately I had to reject it. Things like "thanks" or "hi" are considered noise, and should be removed from posts, not added to them. If you're interested, the relevant discussion is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Using angular:

```
  .directive('cssCounter', ['$document', function($document) {

    function cssFilter(l) {
      return l.type === 'text/css' || l.rel === 'stylesheet';
    }

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

      var links = $document[0].querySelectorAll('link');
      var linksAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(links, 0);
      var cssLinks = linksAsArray.filter(cssFilter);
      var cssNames = cssLinks.map(function(c) {
        return c.href;
      });


      scope.cssFiles = cssNames;
    }

    return {
      link: link,
      template: '<p>CSS count: {{cssFiles.length}}<ul><li ng-repeat="c in cssFiles">{{c}}</li></ul></p>'
    };
  }]);
```

And example plunker can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TqNAOKw4biyA7akdHfa4

Comment: That's better than what I've got. Could you please check what I've got wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/l0Yvgn0PuVZawmiXK4a7?p=info

Comment: @LucasRodrigues you should open up a new question.  However, in your directive, you are looking for `type="text/css"`, but in your html, you specify `rel="stylesheet"`.

Comment: Oh, that's why I was getting an empty array! Plunkr imported those for me, and I didn't pay attention to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using no external libraries, this is how you can do it:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('link');
var linksAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(links, 0);
var cssLinks = linksAsArray.filter(function(l){return l.type === 'text/css';});
var cssNames = cssLinks.map(function(c){return c.href;});
var count = cssNames.length;
console.log("css count and names:", count, cssNames);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I need this implemented in angular js, let me know how to convert the above into angular js